# Can WHERE NOT IN queries cause a table to become corrupted?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, cron

A few months ago I had an issue where my MySQL tables were being constantly corrupted. I talked to support for weeks, changed servers, and even posted a question on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37557909/what-causes-a-corrupted-database-table-to-vanish), but could not find any answers. Since then I rebuilt my database to split the one table into five, and things were fine for around three weeks. Then the same problem happened on one of the tables.

This morning, in a hurry, a created a query to run with cron jobs to search WHERE NOT IN, and this afternoon a second table had crashed. Could the table corruption be linked to the WHERE NOT IN?

The query is

```html
SELECT asin
FROM asin_bsr
WHERE asin NOT IN
     (SELECT asin FROM asin_price)
LIMIT 9
```

asin_bsr is the table that previously had issues, and asin_price is the table that was corrupted today.

Comment: a select does not write to the db, so how could it corrupt it?

Comment: It can however identify a bad sector on disk and cause it to be downed, but this is not the fault of the query, just a function of the disk drive as @Dagon said

Comment: @RiggsFolly yup, if it was me and i had tried all the software methods, i would move the db to a new drive. or at least a new position on the drive

Comment: Here are a [couple](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-common-reasons-for-the-corruption-of-a-MySQL-database) of [things](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15075/why-do-mysql-tables-crash-how-do-i-prevent-it) that may provide some good starting points for troubleshooting.

Comment: Awesome, thank you @Don'tPanic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the corruption could not be linked to WHERE NOT IN.  In terms of altering data or the structure of the database, a SELECT query containing WHERE NOT IN and a SELECT query without it are the same.  That is, SELECT queries do not alter data or the structure of a database.  They are view only.

In the CRUD functions, SELECT queries represent the "R" or "Read".  If your database was somehow being corrupted by SQL code you were running, it would be some operation other than just reading what was there.